# How to prevent Protractor/Jasmine tests from pausing during execution

Tags: automation, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end, pause

So every once in a while, it's honestly hard to if there's a true cause or if this is kind of random, my protractor E2E tests "pause" in execution and in order to "resume" them I have to hit enter in console.

Am I missing a configuration property maybe, or is this just kind of a thing?

If you'd like to see my current config file please just ask, it's a little lengthy so I would like to hold off unless needed.  Wasn't sure if this was a common thing or if there would be an 'off the top of your head' solution.

Running latest version at the time of this post of webdrivers, protractor, and jasmine.

UPDATE (As per comment below):

```
onPrepare: function () {
    global.driver = browser.driver;
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
        if (caps.get('browserName').toLowerCase() == 'chrome' || caps.get('browserName').toLowerCase() == 'firefox' || caps.get('browserName').toLowerCase() == 'microsoftedge') {
            console.log('Chrome, FF, or Edge: skipping browser maximize'); 
        }
        else {
            console.log('FF or IE, using maximize function');
            console.log(caps.get('browserName'));
            var width = 800;
            var height = 600;
            browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
            browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(report);
},
```

I had to use a hacky way to maximize the browser since each browser reacted differently.  So that's the conditional stuff in the on prepare.

At time of the pause:
[image]

Immediately hitting enter quickly runs through the entire spec:
[image]

Comment: Please post at least what do you have in `onPrepare` function and everything you have on the console (important to see at which point the freezing happens). Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe updated as per request with the onPrepare, I'm not sure what you meant by everything I have on the console though.  There aren't error or anything or a prompt to hit enter.  That's just what I have to do to unfreeze the tests.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to ask to see the place and time during a test run when the freezing happens and you have to hit enter. Is it during the startup time, do you see anything printed on the console before the freeze, or may be it freezes between some tests?..

Comment: @alecxe Updated with some console stuff, got lucky and it occurred for me while I was posting this haha. It's like it just forgets what it's doing and then after enter it runs through the spec file it was processing entirely and moves on properly.

Comment: Nice! Do you think it might happen after a test failure? What reporters do you have configured?

Comment: @alecxe I've been noticing it at any point.  Sometimes on first launch, sometimes halfway through a test, passing, failing, it doesn't seem to matter.  I've created my own reporter as of recently, so I'm basically just making calls to an individual JS file that does some writing given the protractor suite/spec/started/done etc methods.  However, it occurred while using protractor-jasmine2-html-screenshot-reporter